# Rhythmyx CMS no items to display, only admins can see anything other than folders

Tags: cms, content

Recently, our CMS system running Rhythmx suddenly stopped displaying items to users and instead is only displaying folders.

The bigger issue however is that admin users can see the files but no other users are able to see it.

Has anyone encountered this before? We have tried a full server reboot to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was related to permissions on the community. A new community was created and that broke the entire ACL thats why only super admins could see content.

We fixed this by removing the newly created community and performing a JBOSS server restart.

Also, it is worth checking there are no issues with LDAP (if your server is using LDAP authentication), since, this being your primary ACL driver would also cause the above issues.

Hope this helps someone in the future.